# What is the wavefunction of a Majorana edge mode in Kitaev's chain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, majorana-fermions

### Kitaev's chain background

Consider Kitaev's chain with the Hamiltonian

$$ H = \sum_n \left( -w c_n^\dagger c_{n+1}+ \Delta c_n c_{n+1} - \frac{\mu}{2} c^\dagger_n c_n\right) + \mathrm{h.c.},$$

where h.c. stands for the Hermitian conjugate and $c_n$ are a set of fermionic modes obeying the anti-commutation relations $\{ c_n,c_m^\dagger \} = \delta_{nm}$ and $\{ c_n,c_m \} = \{c_n^\dagger,c_m^\dagger\} = 0$. Suppose we take the case where $w = \Delta$ and $\mu = 0$, then the Hamiltonian can be written in the Majorana form

$$ H = \sum_n i \gamma_n^A \gamma_{n+1}^B$$

where we have defined the Majorana modes $ \gamma^A_n =-i(c_n-c_n^\dagger)$ and $ \gamma_n^B=c_n+c_n^\dagger$ which obey the algebra $\{\gamma^\mu_m,\gamma^\nu_n\} = 2\delta^{\mu \nu} \delta_{mn}$, where $\mu,\nu \in \{A,B\}$. From these Majorana modes, we can now define a new set of fermionic modes $f_n$ given by

$$ f_n = \frac{1}{2}(i\gamma^A_n+\gamma^B_{n+1}),$$

in which case the Hamiltonian takes the form

$$ H = \sum_n \left(2f^\dagger_n f_n - 1 \right) $$

which is now diagonalised. We see that the Hamiltonian is missing the Majorana modes $\gamma^A_N$ and $\gamma^B_1$ which are located at each end of the chain. Therefore, we can construct one final fermionic mode

$$ F = \frac{1}{2}(i\gamma^A_N+\gamma^B_1)$$

which creates our zero-energy state: a zero mode.

### My question

As the operators $f_n$ obey the fermionic anti-commutation relations, the ground state of the Hamiltonian $H$ should be the state $|\mathrm{GS}\rangle$ such that $f_n |\mathrm{GS}\rangle = 0$ for all $n$, including $F |\mathrm{GS}\rangle = 0$. It is claimed that the Majorana zero mode is a state that is localised on the edges of the system, so I would expect this means the state $F^\dagger |\mathrm{GS}\rangle$ is localised on lattice sites $n=1$ and $n=N$ (for an $N$ site open chain), however I am not sure if this is what it means.

One would assume this means that the single-particle wavefunction of this state is localised on the edges in real space. The wavefunction in position space is given by $\psi_n = \langle n | \psi \rangle$, where $|n\rangle$ are position eigenstates localised on the $n$ lattice site. It seems clear to me that we are ultimately interested in the wavefunction with respect to the original modes $c_n$ because the original Hamiltonian is written down with respect to them. As the original modes $c_n$ have a vacuum state $|0\rangle$ such that $c_n |0\rangle = 0$ for all $n$, we can define the position states via $|n\rangle = c^\dagger_n |0\rangle$. Therefore, I would wrtie down the wavefunction as

$$ \psi_n = \langle 0 | c_n F^\dagger |\mathrm{GS}\rangle. $$

However, note that the vacuum of the $c_n$ modes, $|0\rangle$, is not the same as the vacuum of the $f_n$ modes, $|\mathrm{GS}\rangle$! This is because $c_n |\mathrm{GS}\rangle \neq 0$ for all $n$, therefore it is not clear to me how one would evaluate this. (Maybe the ground state $|\mathrm{GS}\rangle$ is written down as some sort of BCS ground state in terms of the $c_n$ modes?) Additionally, it is not clear to me that this would be localised on the edges.

However, if we instead defined our position basis via $|n\rangle = c_n^\dagger |\mathrm{GS}\rangle$, as done in the answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165022/can-one-define-wavefunction-for-bogoliubov-quasiparticle-excitation-in-a-superco/165047#165047) we would find that we can evaluate this quite simply. We have

$$ \tilde{\psi}_n = \langle \mathrm{GS} | c_n F^\dagger |\mathrm{GS}\rangle $$

Using the fact that

$$  \{ c_n, F^\dagger \} = \frac{1}{2} \{ c_n, c_N - c_N^\dagger + c_1 + c_1^\dagger \} 
 = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{1,n} - \delta_{N,n} )  $$

Therefore we have

$$ \tilde{\psi}_n = \langle \mathrm{GS} | \left(\{ c_n,  F^\dagger \} - F^\dagger c_n \right) |\mathrm{GS}\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{1,n} - \delta_{N,n})$$

where I used the fact that $F|\mathrm{GS}\rangle = 0$. This is nice because it clearly shows that the state is localised on the edges in this sense. However, the state $c^\dagger_n |\mathrm{GS}\rangle$ is clearly not a state that contains a single fermion located on the $n$th lattice site. This is because the ground state is a complicated state that will contain superpositions of particles and holes. Therefore, the wavefunction defined doesn't appear to be a single-particle wavefunction in the sense that it tells us the probability to find a single particle at a particular location.

My question is therefore: What is the wavefunction of a Majorana edge mode in Kitaev's chain?